# RTL Letter spacing issue when using Tajawal

Tags: html, css, fonts, right-to-left, google-fonts

I'm having an issue when trying to use a Google font called Tajawal for my website RTL version. The character's letter spacing is not working as expected. When changing to the default font it works perfectly, but when trying any Google font it's the same issue.

Screenshot :
[image: Text using Tajawal]

I tried:

```
Letterspacing: 0; 
Charset="UTF-8";
```

I'm using the `@import` setting from Google fonts

Comment: Screen shots are impossible to debug. Please include a [example].

Comment: Please choose your tags more carefully. `register-transfer-level: Register-transfer-level (RTL) abstraction is used in hardware description languages like Verilog and VHDL. *Don't use this tag for right-to-left, use [tag:right-to-left]*` Also Use a [repro] to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Thank you all for your feedback. The issue is now fixed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue before, i found out that the problem was from the original document you are copying the text from.
please check the original text remove any spacing or any styling form it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. The issue is now fixed. I didn't pay attention to the original document.